# Error on form validation codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried to do a test on form validation but it gives me always the "unable to connect" message also when I enter a good entries in the form fields . this is my controller script :

```
<?php
public function traitement(){
     $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $pseudo = $this->input->post('pseudo');
    $mdp = $this->input->post('mdp');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pseudo', '"Nom d\'utilisateur"', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mdp',    '"Mot de passe"',       'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
        if($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                // the form is verified
                echo 'connected ';
            }
       else
            {
                //  the form is invalide
                echo 'unable to connect';
            }

}
```

Comment: show the form code

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE`

```
<?php
    public function traitement(){
         $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $pseudo = $this->input->post('pseudo');
        $mdp = $this->input->post('mdp');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pseudo', '"Nom d\'utilisateur"', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mdp',    '"Mot de passe"',       'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
            if($this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE)
                {
                    // the form is verified
                    echo 'connected ';
                }
           else
                {
                    //  the form is invalide
                    echo 'unable to connect';
                }

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```
 <?php
        public function traitement(){
             $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $pseudo = $this->input->post('pseudo');
            $mdp = $this->input->post('mdp');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pseudo', '"Nom d\'utilisateur"', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mdp',    '"Mot de passe"',       'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[52]|alpha_dash|encode_php_tags|xss_clean');
                if(!$this->form_validation->run())
                    {
                        // the form is Invalid
                        echo 'unable to connect ';
                    }
               else
                    {
                        //  the form is valid
                        echo 'connected';
                    }

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem on this rule (xss_clean) when i remove it , no problem detects !